# Why does assigning certain pages to be MasterDetailPage.Master cause the XLS0507 error?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to assign a certain page to be a MasterDetailPage.Master page, using this code.

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:ListPage/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

But it returns error "*XLS0507*"

**Type 'ListPage' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or type converter**

If I assign some other page to be a Master page, it works fine, but this one page doesn't work. 
All I need to know is what exactly this error means.

Edit: Here's the code-behind of ListPage. Read() and Write() are methods used for reading and writing information to and from a file. Read takes file info and puts it into ItemList, and Write takes the stuff from ItemList and puts it in the file.

```
        public ObservableCollection<ListModel> ItemList { get; set; }
        bool newItem = false;
        //create newItem for use in Read/Write
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Items.txt");
        //path is used in Read/Write
        public ListPage(string name, bool NewItem)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            newItem = NewItem;
            ItemList = new ObservableCollection<ListModel>();
            Read();
            if (newItem) { Write(name); }
            PageItemList.ItemsSource = ItemList;
        }
```

Comment: Could you show how does the `ListPage` Page code behind looks like? It seems by the error that you updated the constructor to pass a parameter and you need to also have, as the error says, a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Sure! I just edited the page to feature the Code-behind.

Comment: this tells you exactly what is wrong - "does not define a public parameterless constructor".  XAML can't instantiate the page because it's constructor has parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with the Page Constructor.

In your Constructor, you have indicated that your page will receive two parameters

```
public ListPage(string name, bool NewItem)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   .....
}
```

`name` and `NewItem` but when creating a page from the XAML that page needs to have a parameterless constructor so Xamarin (the framework) is able to create the instance of that class and then display it.

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:ListPage/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Having said the above, you need to remove the two parameters from the constructor

```
public ListPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And with it, you will also need to remove the code inside the constructor leaving only the `InitializeComponent();` method required by Xamarin.

In fact, it's advised to avoid doing operations in the constructor since this can lead to performance issues and/or runtime exceptions. You can move that logic to another method when the Page object is already created, for instance, the `OnAppearing()` is a good place for this.

In your case, if you want to pass those values you can create two `BindableProperty` in your `ListPage` and pass those values in those new properties.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)

Hope this helps.-